# Solving for a variable inside a definite integral

Tags: calculus, integration

I have a rather challenging problem that I don't believe I am capable of solving on my own.

In the case that you don't wish to solve the equation (if it is at all solvable), for all those calculus wizzes out there, answer me this: *how does one solve for a variable inside a definite integral?* Are there tutorials on this subject, or is it even possible?

**solve for c:**
$$\int_0^{100} \Bigg(\ln(\ln(x + 1) + 1)(\frac{11}{10}z + 1)(\frac{(a+1)^c - 1}{(a+1)^c}) + \frac{z}{100}\ln(\ln(101) + 1)(\frac{11}{10}z + 1)(\frac{1}{(a+1)^c})\Bigg)dx$$ -
$$\int_0^{100} \Bigg(\ln(\ln(x + 1) + 1)(\frac{11}{10}z + 1)(\frac{a^c - 1}{a^c}) + \frac{z}{100}\ln(\ln(101) + 1)(\frac{11}{10}z + 1)(\frac{1}{a^c})\Bigg)dx$$ = 
$$\frac{1}{100}\int_0^{100} \Bigg(\frac{21}{10}\ln(\ln(x + 1) + 1) + \frac{21}{1000}\ln(\ln(101) + 1)\Bigg)dx$$

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to do. There are $a,c,z$ variables which have nothing to do with the integral, and the terms involving $a,c,z$ can be 'taken outside' the integral.

Comment: Perhaps I should be been more clear in the post. a and z are other variables. If a solution is possible, c will probably be written in terms of a and z. Also please forgive me, I have not taken multi-variable Calculus yet.

Answer (score 1):

Following on copper.hat's comment there is only one term on the left side in the integral that depend on $x$.  All you need is $\int_0^{100}\ln(\ln(x+1)+1)dx$  [Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral%20%28ln%28ln%28x%2b1%29%2b1%29%20from%200%20to%20100) gives a numeric value of about $151.485$  The same term appears on the right.  Now you have a one-dimensional root-finding problem for $c$ (with $a$ and $z$ inputs) which is treated in any numerical analysis text. I like Brent's method from chapter 9 of Numerical Recipes